# User control(.ascx) and java script functions

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In default.aspx page, there is a user control side_menu.ascx. 
This is part of the code in side_menu.ascx

```
<script src="../library/scripts/side_menu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../library/scripts/side_menu_items.js" type="text/jscript"></script>
<script src="../library/scripts/side_menu_tpl.js" type="text/jscript"></script>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
 <!--
 new menu(SIDE_MENU_ITEMS, SIDE_MENU_POS, SIDE_MENU_STYLES);
 // -->
</script>
```

The function **menu** is defined in side_menu.js. SIDE_MENU_ITEMS is an array containing all the menu items and the path.

```
   var SIDE_MENU_ITEMS =[
["Administration", null,
    ["Report a Bug", "administration/bugs/report_bug.aspx"], // /TOrders/
    ["Bug Tracker", "administration/bugs/bug_tracker.aspx?fmtid=bugs"], // /TOrders/
    ["Feature Request", "administration/features/request_feature.aspx"], // /TOrders/
    ["Feature Tracker", "administration/features/feature_tracker.aspx"] // /TOrders/
]
```

When a menu item is clicked it, it loads the page **/localhost/administration/bugs/whateverpage.aspx.** This works fine. However, when a menu item is clicked the second time the path becomes **/localhost/administration/bugs/administration/bugs/whateverpage.aspx**. THE PATH is getting appended. I just cant figure out where to go and clear the array. When I click on the the menu item, the menu_onnclick() is called and this.item[id] is already populated with the wrong path. Not sure where to clear it.

Here are some of the function in side_menu.js

```
   function menu (item_struct, pos, styles) {
    this.item_struct = item_struct;
this.pos = pos;
this.styles = styles;
this.id = menus.length;
this.items = [];
this.children = [];

this.add_item = menu_add_item;
this.hide = menu_hide;

this.onclick = menu_onclick;
this.onmouseout = menu_onmouseout;
this.onmouseover = menu_onmouseover;
this.onmousedown = menu_onmousedown;

var i;
for (i = 0; i < this.item_struct.length; i++)
    new menu_item(i, this, this);
for (i = 0; i < this.children.length; i++)
    this.children[i].visibility(true);
menus[this.id] = this;
}

  function menu_add_item (item) {
var id = this.items.length;
this.items[id] = item;
return (id);
}  

function menu_onclick (id) {
var item = this.items[id];
return (item.fields[1] ? true : false);
}

    function menu_item (path, parent, container) {
this.path = new String (path);
this.parent = parent;
this.container = container;
this.arrpath = this.path.split('_');
this.depth = this.arrpath.length - 1;
// get pointer to item's data in the structure
var struct_path = '', i;
for (i = 0; i <= this.depth; i++)
    struct_path += '[' + (Number(this.arrpath[i]) + (i ? 2 : 0)) + ']';
eval('this.fields = this.container.item_struct' + struct_path);
if (!this.fields) return;

// assign methods   
this.get_x = mitem_get_x;
this.get_y = mitem_get_y;
// these methods may be different for different browsers (i.e. non DOM compatible)
this.init = mitem_init;
this.visibility = mitem_visibility;
this.switch_style = mitem_switch_style;

// register in the collections
this.id = this.container.add_item(this);
parent.children[parent.children.length] = this;

// init recursively
this.init();
this.children = [];
var child_count = this.fields.length - 2;
for (i = 0; i < child_count; i++)
    new menu_item (this.path + '_' + i, this, this.container);
this.switch_style('onmouseout');
}

function mitem_init() {
document.write (
    '<a id="mi_' + this.container.id + '_'
        + this.id +'" class="m' + this.container.id + 'l' + this.depth 
        +'o" href="' + this.fields[1] + '" style="position: absolute; top: '
        + this.get_y() + 'px; left: '   + this.get_x() + 'px; width: '
        + this.container.pos['width'][this.depth] + 'px; height: '
        + this.container.pos['height'][this.depth] + 'px; visibility: hidden;'
        +' background: black; color: white; z-index: ' + (this.depth + 10000) + ';" ' // changed this.depth to (this.depth + 10000)
        + 'onclick="return menus[' + this.container.id + '].onclick('
        + this.id + ');" onmouseout="menus[' + this.container.id + '].onmouseout('
        + this.id + ');window.status=\'\';return true;" onmouseover="menus['
        + this.container.id + '].onmouseover(' + this.id + ');window.status=\''
        + this.fields[0] + '\';return true;"onmousedown="menus[' + this.container.id
        + '].onmousedown(' + this.id + ');"><div class="m'  + this.container.id + 'l'
        + this.depth + 'i">' + this.fields[0] + "</div></a>\n"
    );
    this.element = document.getElementById('mi_' + this.container.id + '_' + this.id);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Change your array to:**

```
var url="http://"+window.location.hostname;
var SIDE_MENU_ITEMS =[
    ["Administration", null,
        ["Report a Bug", url+"/administration/bugs/report_bug.aspx"], // /TOrders/
        ["Bug Tracker", url+"/administration/bugs/bug_tracker.aspx?fmtid=bugs"], // /TOrders/
        ["Feature Request", url+"/administration/features/request_feature.aspx"], // /TOrders/
        ["Feature Tracker", url+"/administration/features/feature_tracker.aspx"] // /TOrders/
    ]
];
```

**Or *(The more general way for support the urls with port numbers such as `http://localhost:51143/`)*:**

```
function getUrl(){
    url = window.location.href.split('/');
    return url[0]+'//'+url[2];
}
var SIDE_MENU_ITEMS =[
    ["Administration", null,
        ["Report a Bug", getUrl()+"/administration/bugs/report_bug.aspx"], // /TOrders/
        ["Bug Tracker", getUrl()+"/administration/bugs/bug_tracker.aspx?fmtid=bugs"], // /TOrders/
        ["Feature Request", getUrl()+"/administration/features/request_feature.aspx"], // /TOrders/
        ["Feature Tracker", getUrl()+"/administration/features/feature_tracker.aspx"] // /TOrders/
    ]
];
```

Comment: That did it! window.location.hostname returns localhost. But my app runs on localhost:51143. Is there any way of getting this?